# Is there a flutter widget for this type of choice bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

[image: Espn graphic]

This is taken from the ESPN website where you can select one of the 3 options within the choice bar and it shows the information related to your choice. Is there any flutter widget for this? Choice chips are the closest one I've found but they are not connected together. Just wondering if there is a widget for this before spend the time to build one myself.

Comment: I'm not sure is there any package or not, but you create  it easily.

Comment: You can use the TabBar widget from material.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_bar

But, IMHO, your own implementation will be more flexible.

Comment: That looks great, thank you for this pointer! Will probably make my own but having this example to follow is a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in TabBar widget.

Take a look at this article:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs